Need some feedback on an idea for using reinforcement learning in the context of medical imaging reconstruction
Disclaimer -- this idea may be totally half-baked, I'm not sure. I have used deep learning models in image reconstruction before (and this is a super hot topic in the field right now), but only in the context of CNNs. RL is completely new to me. That being said, here's the basic idea:
I'm working with an optimization heuristic for solving a problem in computed tomography (CT) image reconstruction. In a nutshell, you can model a CT system as $Ax + \eta = b$, where $x$ is the unknown image you're trying to recover, $b$ is the measured data (called the sinogram), $\eta$ is the measurement noise and $A$ is the system matrix modeling the acquisition process. In cases where the data is very noisy or the system is highly underdetermined, solving $Ax = b$ using least-squares tends to give unsatisfactory results, so you often want to regularize using some secondary criterion, like total variation (TV).
I've done some work in the past with an optimization heuristic called "superiorization" which attempts to solve this problem via an alternating iterative approach (seeking to minimize the primary objective $\Vert Ax-b \Vert$, i.e. data fidelity, in one step, then the secondary objective, TV, in the alternating step). In order to ensure convergence, you gradually reduce the size of the descent steps for minimizing TV as the algorithm runs. The idea is that you eventually converge to a solution that does as good a job of minimizing $\Vert Ax-b\Vert$ as you would without the TV minimization step, but which should be "superior" with respect to that second criteria. For more details, this paper describes the main ideas: https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.1172
There are a few parameters that need to be specified as part of this heuristic: $N$, the number of descent iterations of TV to perform between each iteration of the data fidelity step, and $\gamma$, which controls the speed at which the TV descent steps decrease (see page 14 of the paper linked above). Generally these are just determined empirically, and I've found that the algorithm can be quite sensitive to them. For example, making $N$ large and $\gamma$ close to 1 may "over-smooth" the image, while making them too small does not provide much benefit. My idea was to see if RL could learn some kind of optimal choices on an iteration-by-iteration basis. In particular, the agent has a choice of two actions: reduce the data fidelity objective, or reduce the TV objective. For now the value of $\gamma$ is still fixed, but this gives the algorithm the choice of how many descent iterations of TV to do between each data fidelity iteration, rather than fixing it at $N$. The state returned by the environment is just the current iterate $x_k$, representing the image being reconstructed, and the reward is $\Vert x_{true} \Vert / \Vert x_{true} - x_k \Vert$; i.e. the reciprocal of the relative error, where $x_{true}$ is the true image. I'm working with synthetic data only at the moment, so the true image is known.
To train the network, I have a set of about 3600 CT image + sinogram pairs. Every episode, one of these is picked at random to train the model. I also have a separate test dataset that I want to evaluate the model on after training, consisting of different images. The images are 512x512 pixels. I'm training it on an undersampled case where the sinograms are only 90 x 729 pixels, which tends to produce significant streaking artifacts in the image, if you don't regularize using something like TV.
I have all this implemented in code using keras-RL just based on some example code I've found online. For the agent we have a sequential model with 3 levels of Conv2D + ReLU + Pooling which reduce the images down to 64x64, followed by a dense layer (about 16 million parameters in total). The policy is BoltzmannQPolicy.
So basically I've trained this for a while, but I'm not sure how much it is actually learning. Even in later episodes it seems like sometimes the reconstruction quality is pretty good, but in other cases it doesn't do enough secondary iterations, and you end up with a pretty streaky image. I am still looking at some parameter tuning, training for longer, etc. but I guess I thought I could just get some input from people with more RL experience about a few things:

Does this seem like an appropriate use case for RL, or is this too ambitious?
Does the training setup make sense? I'm using a large training data set based on my experience with CNNs, but it seems like this is maybe not the way RL models are typically trained. I guess my concern would be that if I train it on the same image over and over (or some very small set of images) then what it learns might not be very generalizable.
Is there a way to restrict what action an agent can take under certain conditions? In order to ensure convergence of the algorithm, it would make sense to have some kind of condition that it has to take Action 1 if it has done a certain number of Action 2 consecutively, but I don't know if this is something that can be built in.
When you test the model (e.g. apply it to new data), is it required that the environment be able to return the reward in addition to the current state? The reason I ask is that the reward in this setting relies on knowing the true image. In a typical CT application you wouldn't actually know what the underlying true image is, if you want to put the algorithm into practice. So is the agent capable of determining actions based only on looking at the state, or does it require knowing the reward as well?

Sorry that this is very long winded, but any input would be appreciated!

You said your loss function is ∥Ax−b∥, then how will you calculate cost function? For example, will you consider region of interest only or entire image? Regarding training image quantity, would you categorize them by body section or all in similar area? I want to know the characteristics of image.
